# What is a Story (Word VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word

this question was partially answered by the question:

[What is a story?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413258/what-is-a-story)

...but the blog it refers to **no longer** exists so I left without a full understanding what a story is in WORD VBA, how they should be used?

It appears to be collection of "bits" of a word document that have common properties such as font, colour, etc and are continuous.  I'm really not sure how to use them, but WORD Object Model constantly refers to stories.

Any help in understanding Stories would be appreciated.

Comment: @WaiHaLee - question refers to your suggested duplicate and states that answer available there has a broken link. What else it should contain to differentiate?

Comment: @MátéJuhász - I think the right course of action would have been to write a comment on the post with the dead link telling the user their link was dead rather than asking a new question. It seems that this question and the other question are equivalent.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Yes, you're right, he could have done that too. That case would have popped up for 2 person; but now it's visible for the whole community; probably I'd also do the same. Also, he don't have enough rep. to comment. Still if one of the questions will get a good answer, than the other one can be marked as duplicate and closed

Comment: In any case, I *have* flagged this post, and I've commented on the answer with the dead link. The author is still active (they were last seen 12 hours ago) so may correct the link. I'll let the community decide what to do here.

Comment: Stackoverflow said I could not comment on the previous question, I did try

Comment: @EricGarlic, I have updated [What is a Story?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413258/what-is-a-story) with additional information.

Answer (score 1):

From http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm :

> ...it is necessary to loop through each individual part of the document. In VBA, these parts are called StoryRanges. Each StoryRange is identified by a unique wdStoryType constant.
>
> There are eleven different wdStoryType constants that can form the StoryRanges (or parts) of a document (ok, a few more in later versions of Word, but they have no bearing in this discussion). Simple documents may contain only one or two StoryRanges, while more complex documents may contain more. The wdStoryTypes that have a role in find and replace are:
>
> wdCommentsStory, wdEndnotesStory, wdEvenPagesFooterStory, wdEvenPagesHeaderStory, wdFirstPageFooterStory, wdFirstPageHeaderStory, wdFootnotesStory, wdMainTextStory, wdPrimaryFooterStory, wdPrimaryHeaderStory, and wdTextFrameStory.

So a story is a specific part of a document, e.g. a header.