# What does enumerations do in word object model in microsoft word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA for word. For a particular purpose, I wanted to move the cursor to the end of the document, while searching the net I found the following code snippet.
`Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory`
, Here my specific question is what is this wdStory? When I searched for this, I got hundreds of such things named enumerations , I want to know why they are used and what does this line interpret to the compiler .

Comment: Enumerations are collections of constants. So all constants as to how far to move selection are in one enumeration. It is for your benefit to make it easy for you to remember as in code they are treated as their literal value (`wdstory = 6`). This is what the compiler sees - `Selection.EndKey Unit:=6` in your named syntax. Compilers use positional so `EndKey(6, False)`.

Comment: See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/enum-statement) and [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.htm) about `Enum` constants; if the flag /"composite" enums   part piques your interest, look into *bitwise operations* too. Cheers!

Comment: Microsoft's enumeration pages show a list of constants (the word form) along with their numeric equivalent (the number form). Here's an example page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdunits It's usually more convenient to use the word form. If you use OLE to control Excel from Word and you haven't referenced the Excel library in your code, the numeric form will work when the word form will not.

Comment: In RTF controls there is only one `wdstory` in a document, the main text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following sophisticated function (I demand full credit)

```
Function ConvertLength(dLength As Double, iOption As Integer) As Double
    If iOption = 0 Then ' from km to m
        ConvertLength = dLength * 1000
    
    ElseIf iOption = 1 Then  ' from m to km
        ConvertLength = dLength / 1000
    
    ElseIf iOption = 2 Then ' from m to cm
        ConvertLength = dLength * 100
    
    ElseIf iOption = 3 Then ' from cm to m
        ConvertLength = dLength / 100
    
    End If
End Function
```

Now we have a problem: Almost every time we use this function we have to consult the documentation to figure out which option to use. For example to convert a length from meters to centimeters, we need to use option 2 and the call would be

```
newVal = ConvertLength(oldVal, 2)
```

Not only is this a nightmare at development time, but every time we read this line, we have to remind ourselves what this option 2 is.

This is where enumerations shine. In this case we would define an enumeration as follows:

```
Enum ConvertOptions
    KmToMeters = 0
    Meters2Km = 1
    Meters2cm = 2
    cmToMeters = 3
End Enum
```

and the function would be re-implemented as

```
Function ConvertLength2(dLength As Double, iOption As ConvertOptions) As Double
    If iOption = KmToMeters Then
        ConvertLength = dLength * 1000
    
    ElseIf iOption = Meters2Km Then
        ConvertLength = dLength / 1000
    
    ElseIf iOption = Meters2cm Then
        ConvertLength = dLength * 100
    
    ElseIf iOption = cmToMeters Then
        ConvertLength = dLength / 100
    
    End If
End Function
```

and we simply use this new function like this

```
newVal2 = ConvertLength2(oldVal, Meters2cm)
```

Here the compiler sees the value `2` instead of `Meters2cm`

Not only is this code much more readable, but the VB editor actually autocompletes our code for us.
[image]

Now, isn't that nice?!

Just like this custom enumeration, word (excel, powerpoint etc) VBA is full of these enumerations (constants). We can safely think of them as integer options we pass to built-in functions/methods to achieve what we want.

Finally if you want to know what a "story" is, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413258/what-is-a-story)